# How to produce a valid json output with array of json objects

Tags: php, json

I created a mySQL database with phpMyAdmin in my local server. In this database I stored the names and the location of my friends (along with an id as a primary key for the database). I wrote and run the following php script to retrieve these data from the database and project them on my local web server (XAMPP):

```
<?php

$dbServername = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'Friends';

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM friends;';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo json_encode($row, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    }
}
```

However, in this way I take this output:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "David Belton",
    "location": "New Haven"
}{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Alex Danson",
    "location": "New York"
}
```

which is not a valid json output overall.
I would like to have the following output:

```
[{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "David Belton",
        "location": "New Haven"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Alex Danson",
        "location": "New York"
  }]
```

(which is also a valid json output)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're echoing out each object in isolation from the others, inside your loop.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    echo json_encode($row, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); //<-- echo out an isolated JSON object
```

Instead, just store everything in an array until you're done then echo out the JSON once, not iteratively.

```
$arr = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) $arr[] = $row;
json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Surely the result of `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` would be the same as `$arr` so possibly an easier solution is to simply `json_encode(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` ? But +1 for explanation.

Comment: The point is to store the retrieved associative arrays in an outer array, then JSON encode that outer array. That produces the output the OP wants.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Perhaps I would like it a bit less dense but it is the right one so it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array and push those records in while loop. At the end `echo json_encode();` so the output will be in proper JSON format

```
$records = array();
if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $records[] = $row;
    }
}
echo json_encode($records, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the result in the array, then echo the encoded/formatted array:

```
<?php

$dbServername = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'Friends';

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM friends;';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$arr = array();

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($arr, $row);
    }
}

echo json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, instead of fetching results one-by-one, just use `mysqli_fetch_all`

```
if ($resultCheck > 0)
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
    echo json_encode($row, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

which is actually faster and uses less memory: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: This is pretty cool(upvote). However keep in mind that this returns an array of arrays and not a simple array.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, this is an array of arrays but in your accepted answer, `$arr` is also an array of arrays

Comment: Haha, I did not realise this even if tested it...also I used finally the second answer...